# how to force to redirect the message on the screen?

Tags: c++, system, redirect

I am running a C++ program and there are other underling code.

When I run it, suppose it is a.exe, there are a lot of information printed on the screen. I can't redirect some information to a .txt file like ./a.ext > temp.txt

How can I force it is redirect to the temp.txt?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your environment? What OS? Are you running a command line application only, or is this a GUI with a secondary text output window?

Answer (score 2):

### POSIX

*Reditect STDOUT and STDERR*

```
./a.ext &> temp.txt
```

Or you can use equivalent from windows format.

```
./a.ext >& temp.txt
```

---

### Windows (Reditect STDOUT and STDERR)

*Reditect STDOUT and STDERR*

```
./a.ext >& temp.txt
```

More information about this you can find at [**Using command redirection operators at Microsoft Technet**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)

Comment: @skydoor: the reason this works is that your output is probably going to stderr, and the above is redirecting stderr (and stdout?) to temp.txt.

Comment: @LarsH: Yes, operator & with > redirecting stderr and stdout, without & operator with same > you redirect only stdout and stderr will push on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the information may be written `stderr`. In order to catch both `stdout` and `stderr`, you should use

```
./a.ext > temp.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: @deus: In what shell environment?